# is same execution plan means same performance?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, sql-execution-plan, inner-query

I have two queries for the same task

**ONE:**

```
select * from table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.id=t2.id
```

**TWO**

```
select * from table1 t1 
INNER JOIN (select * from table2) t2 
ON t1.id=t2.id
```

I checked the execution plan for both the queries.Both execution plans are same.But i doubt ,is there any difference in both the queries? If yes which one is more efficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference. You don't have any extra conditions in inner query. It is a straight select from table. Same happens in the background.

Comment: what if my query is like... select * from table1 t1 
INNER JOIN (select col1,col2 from table2 where 'Some condition') t2 
ON t1.id=t2.id ..then which one is better

Comment: @gkarya42 : Placement of condition doesn't matter in case of inner join. So, they are same. For better readability, use `Table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON AllConditionsHere`